# Setting dimensions of canvas element

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a canvas which I link to a [JSchart](http://www.chartjs.org/). I want the canvas height and width to be set dynamic through JQuery.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="keyFiguresChart"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
this.drawChart();
this.$("#keyFiguresChart").width(800);
this.$("#keyFiguresChart").height(200);
```

When I set the properties height and width before creating the chart, it doesn't work. A standard height and width is then calculated by the JSchart library.

When setting the height and width after creating the chart, the dimensions of the `canvas` are correct but the content is stretched out to match the dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the CSS `width` and `height` properties of the `canvas` which causes it to stretch its contents.  See jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2):

Try setting the `width` and `height` attributes of the element like this:

```
// Assuming you've only got one Canvas on page.
this.$("#keyFiguresChart").attr('width', 800);
this.$("#keyFiguresChart").attr('height', 200);
```